# How to get url of a SharePoint page opened as a form in the page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css, jquery-ui

So I have a SharePoint 2010 site where I have different links on the home page of the site. These links are nothing but aspx pages built in my layout folder.

For ex: My root site page is something like this :
http://abcde/sites/xyz/Sitepages/Test.aspx

And on clicking, one of the link on the page, pops up a form. Further, right click over the form and selecting property I get one property as Address which has url as something :

http://abcde/sites/xyz/_layouts/project/Workflow/qwerty/1234.aspx

and this is the URL I am looking for.

For some reason I need to do some css changes in few pages and for that I am looking to add Jquery as to check the form url loaded and then do the appropiate change. 
I cannot make changes in css class directly as the class is getting referred in other pages too.

Using `Window.location.href` or `SpPageContext_Info` returns the rooturl i.e. http://abcde/sites/xyz/Sitepages/Test.aspx

Can anyone suggest me how should I fix this or is there any other approach?

**Note**:I cannot use a Content Editor Webpart on this aspx pages

Thank You!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes what you need to do is open the server side file under program files\common files\web server extensions\12 (or version number) \ then under layouts you will see some ascx files. You may have to do a search. But those are sometimes used in many underlying _layouts aspx pages. You have dig in and see which relate to you.

Looks like you are /project/workflow add-on or something so it may be custom. Try even looking in that folder path as well.

Once you identify the ascx page you can edit it and add a custom css there using  ...

Hope that gives you a general direction.

Comment: YEs thats what I did.. But what I was looking for to get the address of the form by using jquery  and then implement the css for that page, but anyhow, this resolves the issue and that is what matters :)